# C# Lambda with Entity Framework - Return a result even when no match

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

The code below is working, but if it can't find an entry with "Domain Administrator" as per the where clause it will completely ignore anything else on that particular result. This leads to me missing items, as the view I am generating may not have a "Domain Administrator" entry. I understand that this is because it is an explicit where, but I'm not quite sure how to represent exactly what I need to do. I suspect I need to do a LEFT JOIN, but not sure how this then effects the navigation properties. Any guidance into the right direction would be appreciated.

```
var endpointConstructor = db.tbl_equipment.Include(t => t.tbl_Backup_Configuration)
   .Where(e => e.tbl_Backup_Configuration.FirstOrDefault().BackupType == null)
   .Where(e => e.tbl_customer.Calc_Contract_Status == true && e.Calc_Contract_Status == true && e.Equip_type.Contains("server")).OrderBy(e => e.tbl_customer.Priority)
   .Where(what => what.tbl_customer.tbl_user_pass_list.FirstOrDefault().Usage1 == "Domain Administrator")
   .Select(s => new CompanyServerUserPassViewModel { Comp_ID = s.Comp_ID, ServerName = s.NetBIOS_name, AdminUsername = s.tbl_customer.tbl_user_pass_list.FirstOrDefault().Username,
   AdminPassword = s.tbl_customer.tbl_user_pass_list.FirstOrDefault().Password, Company = s.Company, TeamviewerID = s.tbl_computerinfo.FirstOrDefault().teamviewerID });
```

Comment: `FirstOrDefault().Password` As a side note, you understand what the "default" here is and that it will throw if you ask for properties?

Comment: Yes - I'd assume it would throw null when it doesn't exist?

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of:

```
.Where(what => [statement that evaluates to true if there is no domain admin] 
|| what.tbl_customer.tbl_user_pass_list.First().Usage1 == "Domain Administrator")
```

Comment: Would that not simply evaluate everything thus rendering the line pointless?

If I actually remove the .Where clause for domain administrator it returns everything I need, but on the items where Domain Administrator doesn't exist it is populating my view with another type of username/password in list. What I'd like to do is return the values if they are of type Domain Administrator, but return null if there are not any with type of Domain Administrator.

Comment: "but if it can't find an entry with "Domain Administrator" as per the where clause it will completely ignore anything else on that particular result" I thought you wanted it to return values in the case of there not being a Domain Admin.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, say I have a Company called Contoso Ltd and a servername called SERVER1. If that has an entry in tbl_user_pass for Domain Administrator, my code works fine and returns everything in the resultset and all is well. If it doesn't have a domain administrator, it emits Contoso Ltd and Servername from the resultset entirely. Now Contoso Ltd may have an entry in tbl_user_pass for say a printer. If I implement your code it would return Contoso Ltd, SERVER1, PrinterUsername, PrinterPassword. What I actually want to return is Contoso Ltd, SERVER1, null, null.

Comment: moves the where's into the selects?

Comment: I did try that but couldn't get the syntax right, I'd massively appreciate an example line. I think the tbl_user_pass_list being a collection makes it more difficult.

Comment: I find your use case a bit confusing. I'll come back and look if I have time. May be worth checking up the syntax and reducing it down to a simplified example to attract more answers.